# Shorthand way to populate a list of objects from a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the following to populate a list of objects using a `for` loop:

```
const foo = ['bar', 'hello', 'world']

const things = []
foo.forEach((x) => {
    things.push({
        name: x,
        age: 1
    })
})
```

This strikes me as a bit convoluted. In Python there's a concept of list comprehension which would allow me to do:

```
foo = ['bar', 'hello', 'world']
things = [{name: x, age:1} for x in foo]
```

Is there an equivalent in JavaScript? Is there a better way to populate `things` than my JavaScript snippet?

Answer (score 5):

You could map the objects with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and take a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for `name`.

```js
const
    foo = ['bar', 'hello', 'world'],
    things = foo.map(name => ({ name, age: 1 }));

console.log(things);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const foo = ['bar', 'hello', 'world']

const things = foo.map((name) => {return {name, age:1}});
console.log(things);
```

Comment: You don't need `return` in one-liner arrow functions.

Comment: @Barmar - True, I was planning to edit too, but there is another answer doing the same - did not found appropriate. Thank you!